# How to set limit to 4 users?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have this section on my website: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN0PH.jpg "section"

I want to limit this photos to show max. 4 contacts, because if I have more, it looks bad.How can I add to this a max. limit to show?Sorry for so much code but I don't know exactly where is my function.Thank you.

**Here is my view:**

```
<!-- Tabs Widget -->


<div class="tab-content" style="padding: 8px !important">
                <?php $count_user = 0; ?>

                @foreach($user->contact as $contact)
                    <div id="contact<?php echo $count_user++; ?>" class="tab-pane magazine-sb-categories <?php if($count_user == 1){ echo "active"; } ?>">
                        <div class="row team-v1">


                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom: -10px">
                    <li><h3 style="margin-top: 5px !important;text-transform: none; " >
                        @if($contact->role[0]->slug == "individuals")
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;" class="icon-user"></i>

                                    @elseif($contact->role[0]->slug =='organizations')
                                        <i style="font-size: 13px;" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
                                    @endif

                                    <a style="font-size: 14px" href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $contact->username }}">{{ $contact->username  }}</a></h3>
                                <p>
                    <strong><i class="icon-real-estate-020 u-line-icon-pro"></i> : </strong><a>{{ $contact->country->country }}</a><br>
                    <strong><i class="icon-screen-tablet fa-" aria-hidden="true"></i> : </strong><a>{{ $contact->industry->industry }}</a><br>
                    @if($contact->role[0]->slug == "individuals")
                                                    @foreach($contact->career_path as $career_path)
                                                        <i style="font-size: 13px" class="icon-speedometer"></i> : {{ $career_path->functions->function }}
                                                        @break;
                                                    @endforeach
                                                @elseif($contact->role[0]->slug =='organizations')

                                                    <i style="font-size: 13px" class="icon-frame fa-"></i> : {{ $user->organization_type->organization_type }}<br>
                                                @endif


                        </p>
                    </ul>



                        </div>
@endforeach
```

**Here is my User.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $fillable = [
    //     'name', 'email', 'password',
    // ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    // protected $hidden = [
    //     'password', 'remember_token',
    // ];

    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }

    public function country()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Country','country_id','id');
    }



    public function organization_type()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrganizationType');
    }

    public function industry()
    {
        // return $this->hasOne('App\Country','state_country_id','id');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Industry');
    }


    public function career_path()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CareerPath');
    }


    public function education()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Education');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\About');
    }

    public function portfolio()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Portfolio');
    }

    public function language_skills_selected()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\LanguageSkill','language_skills_selected','user_id','language_skills');
    }

     public function offices_branch()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OfficesBranch');
    }

    public function my_alert()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\MyAlert');
    }

    public function privancy_setting()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PrivancySetting');
    }

    public function event()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\News');
    }

    public function opinion()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Opinion');
    }

    public function career_solution()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CareerSolution');
    }


    public function contact()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id');
     }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','user_id','contact_id');
    }




}
```

Comment: Hi there! I think we may need a bit more context... do you want to limit it when it gets pulled from the DB or after? Which variable are you referring to?

Comment: Hello.I want to set limit for elements when it s pulled from DB. Because, like in photo, isn't look nice.So, I need to add a limit for showing elements :) I'm referring to this foreach `@foreach($user->contact as $contact)` .Please check my updated ask.

Comment: Something like...limit(4)->latest();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function contact() 
{ 
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->limit(4); 
}
```

This should be done in User.php.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know exactly where should I put this.Maybe you can help me a little?Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to put it here, but doesn't without effects: ` $data['user'] = User::with('career_path.industry','career_path.department','career_path.functions','education.field_of_study','education.degree','privancy_setting')->where('username', '=' ,$username)->take(2)->firstOrFail();
`

Comment: no you don't user first or fail when you use take(). just add this ->take(5)->get(); or alternatively you can use this ->limit(5)
                ->get();

Comment: what is the name of the variable from your code let me write it for you, sorry but your code isn't well formatted

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but isn't my code...I just need to repair a bug but I'm not doing great with backend:) I'm using this variable to generate username/image profile etc. `@foreach($user->contact as $contact)`

Comment: firstOrFail was there before adding `take(2)`, so maybe it s important somewhere.I just need some help to find out the correct variable from controller, and where should I add this `take/limit`

Comment: This is line of code that get the contacts from the user right   public function contact() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->take(4)-get(); }  or public function contact() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->limit(4)->get(); }

Comment: Or neatly you can do this $user->contact()->with('photo')->limit(4);  Note: photo should be a column from the contact table

Comment: I've got this error, with that public contact: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`

Comment: With limit. For generating photos I'm using this: `<?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>`

Comment: Did you try this? This is line of code that get the contacts from the user right public function contact() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->take(4) } or public function contact() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->limit(4); }

Comment: Oh, thank you so much bro! this works `public function contact() { return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id')->limit(4); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196862/discussion-between-okere-chukwudi-and-andrei-nagy).

Comment: Can you help me with another eloquent problem please?

Comment: Can you create a new question and share the link so we don't stretch this comment?

Comment: Can we talk in chat maybe?I can't make another question for moment

Comment: Here is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081955/how-to-use-roles-in-my-career-solution-section

Comment: That's very fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship set up for `$user->contact` (i.e. hasMany), you should be able to call it like this in your loop in your blade file:

```
$limitedContacts = $user->contact->limit(4);

@foreach($limitedContacts as $contact)
     ....
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I've got an error: `Method limit does not exist.`.  Here is my public function contact, from User.php, if helps you : `public function contact()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','contacts','contact_id','user_id');
    }
`